# Reading a file where middle name is optional

Tags: c++, string, file, file-io, cin

I'm trying to read in a file formatted as

> firstName middleName<sub>(optional)</sub> lastName petName\n

With the middle name being there on half the entries, I'm unsure as to the best way to read these in and get them into the correct variable names. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how readdir would help in this example, that just lists files and folder in a directory doesnt it? I'm reading the file in using ifstream, the problem is I'm not sure what the string operations would be.

Comment: I misread your question as the format being the name of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like  this:

```
std::string line, word;
while (std::getline(myFile, line)) {
    if (line.empty()) continue;        

    // read words from line:
    std::istringstream is(line);
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    words.reserve(4);
    for (int i = 0; is >> words && i < 4; i++)
        words.push_back(word);

    if (words.size() == 4)
        // middle name was present ...
    else
        // it was not ...
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; is >> words; i++)` or simply `while (is >> words)`?

Comment: @0x499602D2:: Heh, sorry. When I was typing it I wanted to put there `i < 4` as well so that no more words is read.

Answer (score 1):

If only middleName is optional, you can split the line and keep words in a `std::vector<std::string>`. Then check if size of `vector` is 4, then you have the middleName. If size is 3, you don't.